# Notification does not vibrate when triggered

Tags: android, notifications, android-vibration

I am working on an app in android in which i wish to notify specific users about specific events. These notifications are made by using the the Firebase Cloud Messaging data-messages. When I send a **data-message** to the users client, the onMessageReceived-method is called and I can handle these messages as I wish.

Now I want to make the device vibrate in the very moment the messages arrives. Therefore, I tried to build a notification and set the vibration on it, however it does not vibrate at all..

I included the VIBRATE-permission in my applications Manifest as well.

Here is my Code to build the notification:

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon)
                            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                            .setContentText("Content Text")
                            .setVibrate(new long[] {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500});

            Notification note = mBuilder.build();
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, note);
```

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.text))
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);


        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500});
        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);


        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        mNotifyMgr.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

This works for me.

Comment: Nevermind. I just realized that my device has a malfunction. This answer works for me, thanks!